# How to detect if some page template has been selected

Tags: pages, page-template, homepage, frontpage

I'm wondering if, in the static front page, is possible to detect if the some page template has been selected for my page. 
I'm building a template and I'd like to have a static front page, but I'd like to load a particular page-template just in the case my client selected it in the page Attributes, otherwise will be load the standard page structure.

Is it possible?

Thank you for any help or clue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure it is possible. Just check the page meta field (assuming you're in the loop):

```
$template = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_wp_page_template', true );
```